# Why it different when the start() command is placed?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

I tried to put f1.start(); command at the main (when i marked it with B)
and it gives me an error and i am tryin to understand why.
so i changed it to where it is now, and my program compiles as it should be,
im just curious why.
thanks.

```
package Try;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo1 extends Thread {

    private int min_, max_;
    Foo1(int max, Integer min) {

    max_ = max;
    min_ = min.intValue();
    }

    public void run() {

        Random rand_gen = new Random();
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(rand_gen.nextInt(max_-min_) + min_);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("you got new message");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Insert 1 to start"); // C

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // D

        int i = sc.nextInt();

        if (i == 1) {
            Foo1 f1;
            //f1.start(); // B
            int max = 1000;
            Integer min = new Integer(1000);
            Foo1 f2 = new Foo1(max, min);
            f1 = f2; // A
            f1.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you asked why it is giving you an error, why did not you tell what the error it was, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Because you declared `f1` but you didn't initialize the variable with an instance of `Foo1`.

Have a look here for more information: [A Guide to Creating Objects in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialization)

Comment: Thanks! maybe you know i have one more question. - why at line //C, the method println() can be accessed even though there is no object from type System? 
I know its relevent to class initialization under the linking process but cant put on why..

Comment: @LorinSherry It's explained here: [System.out.println](https://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/)

Comment: thanks, ive read, its because System is a final class?

Comment: @LorinSherry It's not about the *final*. It's about the fact that ```out``` is a *static* variable of ```System```. Static variables (and functions) don't need an instance of the class they are declared in to be accessed (or called). The non-static method ```println``` is a method on the variable ```out``` which holds an ```PrintStream``` instance. More to read: [static keyword in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-java/)

Comment: @LorinSherry, Actually, just to be crystal clear, `println` is not a method on the variable `out`. It's a method of the _object_ to which the `out` variable refers. Variables in Java (unlike in C++) never are objects in their own right. They only ever _refer_ to objects that have methods and fields.

Comment: thanks alot. how it relevent to class initialization under the linking process?

Comment: @SolomonSlow maybe do you know?

Comment: @LorinSherry, The question that you asked--the reason for the error message at `//B`--has been answered. If you have other questions, then you should post those separately instead of trying to continue a conversation in the comments here.